# Mean and variance of a non-standard pdf

Tags: variance, density-function, nonparametric, numerical-integration

I have tried to compute the variance and the  mean for $\mu=0.5$ of the following PDF using Wolfram cloud but I failed 
$$ F(z,\mu,\sigma)=\frac{2 (z-\sigma )^2 \exp \left(-\frac{(z-\sigma )^2
   \sqrt{\left(1+0.25 \mu ^2\right) 2 \pi } \text{erf}\left(\frac{(z-\sigma )^2
   \sqrt{\left(1+0.25 \mu ^2\right) 2 \pi }}{1+0.25 \mu ^2}\right)}{1+0.25 \mu
   ^2}\right)}{\pi ^2 \sqrt{\left(1+0.25 \mu ^2\right) 2 \pi }} $$

**Note**: $\mu \in (0,1)$, $z , \sigma$ are reals and the integrand of that PDF is over $\sigma $

I have doubts this is a valid PDF formulation, However I have confirmed many times that is correct , the message I have got from Mathematica is " The integrand has evaluated to non numerical value for a sampling points in the region of boundaries region $(-\infty,0)$. Maybe the integrand does not converge under the conditions which I have assumed.

Comment: 1) Kindly add the self-study tag. 2) You appear to have posted a CDF instead of a PDF. Consider the behavior of a CDF towards $+\infty$ and if such a function could have a finite integral on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes , The integration of that Function over R  is a CDF , The limit is finit and lie between 0.96 and 1.04  if am true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplifications:**

1. replace 
   $$\frac{(z-\sigma )^2
      \sqrt{\left(1+0.25 \mu ^2\right) 2 \pi }}{1+0.25 \mu ^2}$$
   by
   $$\frac{(z-\sigma )^2
      \sqrt{2 \pi }}{\sqrt{1+0.25 \mu ^2}}$$
2. replace$$z-\sigma$$by $y$
3. replace $\text{Erf}(x)$ with
   $$\text{Erf}(x) = 2\Phi(x\sqrt{2}) - 1$$

This leads to consider instead
$$\frac{2 y^2}{\pi^2\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left\{-\sqrt{2\pi}y^2 \text{erf}\left(y^2
   \sqrt{2 \pi }\right)\right\}=\frac{2 y^2}{\pi^2\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left\{-\sqrt{2\pi}y^2 \left[2\Phi(2y^2\sqrt{\pi}) - 1\right]\right\}$$
Operate the change of variable $w=y^2\in(0,\infty)$, leading to
$$\frac{w^{1/2}}{\pi^2\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left\{-\sqrt{2\pi}w \left[2\Phi(2w\sqrt{\pi}) - 1\right]\right\}$$
which integrates to something of the order $10^{-2}$ over $(0,\infty)$ and is thus improperly normalised.

Comment: Is there any possibility to Normalise it ? just to tell me , if no let me know and i do not want wasting my time if it is not possible

Comment: If you divide this function by its integral, which is finite, then it gets normalised.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this should be a comment or an answer but because this question was simultaneously posted on multiple forums, I placed an answer at [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212253/compute-moments-variance-skewness-mean-from-the-pdf-of-a-non-standard-distrib).

In short the pdf is approximately

$$1.0105750026505362 \times \frac{\sqrt[4]{2 \pi }}{\sqrt[4]{1+ \mu^2/4}} \frac{(z-\sigma )^2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}{\sqrt{1+ \mu^2/4}}
\exp\left(-\frac{(z-\sigma )^2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}{\sqrt{1+ \mu^2/4}}
\text{erf}\left(\frac{(z-\sigma )^2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}{\sqrt{1+ \mu^2/4}}\right) \right)$$

The mean is $\sigma$ and because of the symmetry of the pdf all odd central moments are zero.  The variance only depends on $\mu$:

$$0.282617 \sqrt{\mu ^2+4}$$

(Not that it's wrong but I have no idea why the parameters are labeled $\sigma$ and $\mu$, respectively, rather than the other way around.)